# evitar pegar valores alfanumericos en un texbox en html

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy iniciando en programación y me solicitaron validar el ingreso de campos alfanuméricos en un `texbox`. Ya puedo validar que no los puedan escribir, sin embargo, en el momento que pegan un caracter, si permite realizar esta acción.

Cómo puedo evitar esto?, muchas gracias.

la función `javascript` que tengo hasta el momento es la siguiente:

```
function Alphanumeric(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;    
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if ((charCode == 32) || (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) || (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) || (charCode == 8))        
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del evento `paste` al cual le previenes el comportamiento *por defecto* impidiendo que se lleve a cabo; es decir que se logre pegar contenido en el `input`

Te coloco el siguiente ejemplo donde:

- Recupero un `input` por su `id` le agrego un *handler* a su evento `paste`
- En la función que paso le asigno un argumento que *leerá* el evento
- Dentro del cuerpo de la función le indico que se prevenga dicho comportamiento

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <input id="probando" type="text" />
    <div id="aviso"></div>
    <script>
        let probando = document.getElementById("probando")
        let aviso = document.getElementById("aviso")
        
        probando.addEventListener("paste", (event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          aviso.innerHTML = "No se permite pegues valores"
        })
    </script>
```

Opcionalmente le puedes agregar un aviso posterior a que inhabilitas dicho comportamiento para hacerle saber que no esta permitido el pegar contenido, con lo cual condicionas al usuario a que escriba de forma directa; entonces conjuntas esto con tu validación.

**Referencia**

- [evento `paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event)